# Align text by 16 characters

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function to center text on a 16*8 screen (8 lines and 16 letters in one line), the part with a length < 16 is working fine but when i have more than one line i can't find how to solve the problem, here is my code :

```
char* align_text(char* text)

    int i=0, j=0, k;
    int modulo, diff;
    int size = strlen(text);
    char space[16];
    char tmp[16];
    char tmp2[16];
    char* tmp3;

    char median[150];
    char* final;

    if(size==16)
        return text;
    else if(size<16)
    {
        diff = 16 - size;
        modulo = diff%2;
        if(modulo==0)
        {
            for(j=0;j<diff/2;j++)
                space[j] = ' ';
            space[j] = '\0';
            strcat(median, space);
            strcat(median, text);
            strcat(median, space);
        }
        else
        {
            for(j=0;j<(int)(diff/2);j++)
                space[j] = ' ';
            space[j] = '\0';
            strcat(median, space);
            strcat(median, text);
            space[j] = ' ';
            space[j+1] = '\0';
            strcat(median, space);
        }
        final = (char*)malloc(strlen(median)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(final, median);
        return final;
    }
    else
    {
        while(text[i] != '\0')
        {

            if(text[i] == ' ')
            {
                if(strlen(tmp2)>16 && strlen(tmp)<=16)
                {
                    tmp3 = align_text(tmp);
                    if(strlen(median) == 0)
                        strcpy(median, tmp3);
                    else
                        strcat(median, tmp3);
                    free(tmp3);
                    j=0;
                    tmp2[0] = '\0';
                    i = k;
                }

                strcpy(tmp, tmp2);
                tmp2[j++]=text[i++];
                tmp2[j]='\0';
                k = i;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp2[j++]=text[i++];
                tmp2[j]='\0';
            }
        }

        if(strlen(tmp2)>16 && strlen(tmp)<=16)
        {
            tmp3 = align_text(tmp);
            if(strlen(median) == 0)
                strcpy(median, tmp3);
            else
                strcat(median, tmp3);
            free(tmp3);
        }

        j=0;
        tmp2[0] = '\0';
        i = k;

        while(text[i] != '\0' )
        {
            tmp2[j] = text[i];
            tmp3 = align_text(tmp2);
            strcat(median, tmp3);
            free(tmp3);
        }

        final = (char*)malloc(strlen(median)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(final, median);
        return final;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the text is > 16 in length? Just wrap and stay centered?

Comment: Yes I just want it to be in the center of the screen (the same number of space right and left)

Comment: So the function returns the string? And if it wraps, which piece of the string is supposed to be returned?

Comment: The function returns only one string with spaces added in the right places.

Comment: In the statement, `if(strlen(tmp2)>16 && strlen(tmp)<=16)` it's possible `tmp` or `tmp2` haven't been set to anything yet?

Comment: I think it's better to store and print the lines seperately instead of inserting spaces around the words like you did

Comment: Yes, I think that printing each line will be way easier, I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this works after some testing. I won't claim a high "level of elegance", but it's clean and functional.

The approach here is that it takes the input as one null-terminated string of text. A copy of the input string is made since `strtok` is used to pull out each non-blank string, and `strtok` modifies the string. The output is managed by building it a single line at a time (in the `line` buffer), then centering that line when it's deemed full as it is copied to the output. The function, `format_line`, does the copy of a line to the output that must be centered. If you want left or right justification, that could be done just by modifying `format_line`. Because `strtok` is used to pull "tokens" from the input with blank delimiters, a single blank is re-inserted between each word on output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


static const int cols = 16;
static const int rows = 8;


void format_line(char *out_text, char line[], int col)
{
    int nspaces;

    // Back off the trailing space if there is one
    //
    if ( line[col-1] == ' ' )
        col -= 1;

    line[col] = '\0';

    // Center the text to the output buffer
    //
    nspaces = cols - col;

    memset(out_text, ' ', nspaces/2);
    out_text += nspaces/2;

    *out_text = '\0';

    strcat(out_text, line);
    out_text += strlen(line);

    memset(out_text, ' ', nspaces - nspaces/2);
    out_text += nspaces - nspaces/2;

    *out_text = '\0';
}


char *align_text(char *text)
{
    int col, row;
    char *fit_text, *ret_text;
    char *np;
    char line[cols+1];
    char *ptext;

    // Copy the input text so we don't destroy the original w/strtok
    ptext = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
    strcpy(ptext, text);

    // Create the buffer for the output text
    ret_text = fit_text = malloc(cols * rows + 1);

    // Initialize the working line/row
    line[col = 0] = '\0';
    row = 0;

    // Parse each string in the input text with space as delimeter
    //
    for (np = strtok(ptext, " "); (np != NULL) && (row < rows); np = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        // If the next string fits on the current line
        //   then we'll put it there
        //
        if ((col + strlen(np)) < cols)
        {
            col += strlen(np);
            strcat(line, np);

            // Append a space delimeter if there's room
            //
            if (col < cols)
                line[col++] = ' ';

            line[col] = '\0';

            // If we hit the end of the line, copy it to the output text
            // buffer and reset the to the beginning of the working line
            //
            if (col == cols)
            {
                memcpy(fit_text, line, col);
                fit_text += cols;
                line[col = 0] = '\0';
                row += 1;
            }
        }
        else  // The next string doesn't fit on the current line
        {
            // If there is text on the current line, then
            //    space pad it, append it to the output (centered), and reset working line
            //
            if ( col > 0 )
            {
                format_line(fit_text, line, col);
                fit_text += cols;
            }

            // If the current string is longer than a line, then
            // copy over the long chunks
            //
            while ( strlen(np) >= cols )
            {
                memcpy(fit_text, np, cols);
                fit_text += cols;
                np += cols;
                row += 1;
            }

            // Copy the rest of the current string to the fresh working line
            //
            strcpy(line, np);
            col = strlen(np);
            line[col++] = ' ';
            line[col] = '\0';
            row += 1;
        }
    }

    // Copy over and center the last one
    //
    if ( (col > 0) && (row < rows) )
    {
        format_line(fit_text, line, col);
        fit_text += cols;
    }

    *fit_text = '\0';

    return ret_text;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( argc > 1 )
    {
        printf("%s\n", align_text(argv[1]));
        printf("0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I think I didn't explain enough what I want to do. This function works well but I don't want to have a cut word.
For exemple the string: "Hello how are you" will be cut at "Hello how are yo" so I will have this first part on the first line and only "o" in the center of the second line.

Comment: I tested it and it works fine ! Thank you. It's even managing words that don't fit in one line. I haven't think about the strtok function to get each word, well thank you anyway

Comment: @Bash yes, `strtok` is quite handy pulling substrings out of a longer string delimited by a given set of characters, in this case, a space. Two disadvantages to `strtok` are (1) it alters the string you're scanning (it changes some of the delimiters to null for parsing), and (2) if you scan for more than one delimiter, it doesn't tell you which one it found. In the above code, you could generalize to more delimiters (like hyphen) by making a custom function that's like `strtok`. For this specific case, it worked well.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum { left, center, right } position;

int pos_calc(int width, int max_width, position pos){
    int d;
    if((d=max_width - width)< 0)
        return -1;

    switch(pos){
    case   left: return 0;
    case  right: return d;
    case center: return d/2;
    }
}

char *puton(char *buff, int width, position pos, const char *data){
    int len = strlen(data);
    int offset = pos_calc(len, width, pos);
    memset(buff, ' ', width);
    buff[width]='\0';
    memcpy(buff + offset, data, len);
    return buff;
}

char* join(char c, size_t arrsize, const char *arr[]){
    size_t i, total, len[arrsize];
    char *buff, *ret;

    for(total=i=0;i<arrsize;++i)
        total+=(len[i]=strlen(arr[i]));
    if(NULL==(ret=buff=malloc((total + arrsize)*sizeof(char))))
        return NULL;
    for(i=0;i<arrsize;++i){
        memcpy(buff, arr[i], len[i]);
        buff+=len[i];
        *buff++=c;
    }
    *--buff='\0';
    return ret;
}

char *align_text(const char *str){
    static const int row = 8;
    static const int col = 16;
    static const char *delimiter = " \t\n";

    char *text = strdup(str);
    char *words[col], *p, *cat;
    int wc, total_len, r;
    char *buff = malloc(row * col * sizeof(char) + 1);
    //memset(buff, ' ', row*col);
    //buff[row*col] = '\0';
    for(r=total_len=wc=0, p=strtok(text, delimiter); p ; p = strtok(NULL, delimiter)){
        int len = strlen(p);
        //if(len > col){...}
        words[wc++] = p;
        total_len += len;
        if(total_len  + wc - 1 > col){
            cat = join(' ', wc - 1, words);
            puton(buff + col * r++, col, center, cat);
            //if(r >= row){...}
            free(cat);
            words[0] = words[wc-1];
            wc = 1;
            total_len = len;
        }
    }
    cat = join(' ', wc, words);
    puton(buff + col * r++, col, center, cat);
    free(cat);
    free(text);
    return buff;
}

void print(const char *text, int width){
    int i;
    for(i=1;*text;++i){
        putchar(*text++);
        if(i % width == 0)
            putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(){
    char *text = align_text("Hello how are you");
    //printf("%s", text);
    print(text, 16);
    free(text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Answer with code only are bad. At least comment what you ve done.

Comment: I haven't try your code but it looks kind of complicated for what I want to do. I'm not saying that's it's not correct but I would rather try another solution than this one.

Comment: It is simple, rather than complicated. Bash's code is complex, and it's a bad idea as  return of value.